# How to add custom textures to a sprite animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

this has been causing me some frustration the last couple of days.

I have a run.atlas file which shows my game character running. My game character has some complex shapes that spriteKit isnt doing a good job of recognizing so character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: characterTexture) is not working properly since the drawing has some disconnected elements.

What I tried to do in photoshop is make an outline of the character and use that as the texture, which works.

```
let firstFrame = SKTexture(imageNamed: "run1Texture")
    stickman = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "run1")
    stickman.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: firstFrame, size: firstFrame.size())
```

As you can see what I am doing is loading the image but using the custom frame as the skphysics body.

Now I need a way of doing this for the entire animation which is 7 frames. 
How can i change the skphysics body during the animation? or is there maybe a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A physics body does not change itself once created. If you want to change/modify a node's physics body, you will have to destroy it first `physicsBody = nil` and then created a new one.

I suggest you try creating a physics body which is sufficient for all your animation frames, as constantly creating and destroying a physics body is not an efficient way to go.